# How Google Drive API updates Sep 13, 2021 affect authenticate with pydrive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

Like a lot of users, I just got [this mail](https://forums.solar2d.com/t/email-from-google-action-required-drive-api-requires-updates-to-your-code-before-sep-13-2021/353804), of google drive security updates.
I'm currently using Pydrive with python to send files from PC to google drive, for that I've got an API key and created a credentials file, and saved it for automatic authentication ([as described here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-connect-google-drive-to-python-using-pydrive-9681b2a14f20))
I didn't understand from this mail what are the exact steps I need to take in order to not being affected by these google drive security updates.
My questions are:

1. What do I need to update in the credential file? or in the Pydrive code? and how?
2. My Gdrive folder is Shared with other users, Do I need to do something that they still be shared in that folder?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking the blog post for any updates on this change [blog update](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2021/06/drive-file-link-updates.html).

There are also a number of Issue on the tracker requesting more information regarding the resource key and how it should be used and requested: [resourceKey usage is not clear](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196982369?pli=1)

I dont think we will get a clear idea of how it will work until its released.